# How to migrate the existing httpUser to FastHttpUser without making significant change. Is it possible?

Tags: python, windows, locust

I am not sure why locust is throwing below error when I increase users/second on my windows server machine. So many people have reported this but I doubt this is still solved. After further deep dive I realized that this is the python limitation from the pool manager or something. What does locust suggests here.

```
connectionerror(protocolerror('connection aborted.', remotedisconnected('remote end closed connection without response')))
```

**Question** : I have my framework supporting HttpUser. What changes are required to migrate to FastHttpUser. I have gone through the example on locust documentation but seems like it is huge change I need to make. Can't I just replace `httpsUser` to `FastHttpUser`?

Using windows server 2016.
Python 3.8.10
Locust : latest 2.15.1

Tried increasing the Pool size of UrlLib3. Did not work.
Tried changing httpUser to FastHttpUser but it failed in auth and throwing 401

Answer (score 0):

”remote end closed connection without response” means that your *server* failed to respond correctly.

This is very unlikely to be a Locust problem. Switching to FastHttpUser could give you a more (or less) descriptive error message, but it is unlikely to work around the issue.

If you want to investigate the 401, maybe try tracing the request as documented at the bottom of this page https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-debugger.html